How to integrate jQuery dependent plugins into Laravel 11 with Vite
I'm developing a web project with Laravel 11 in which I want to integrate some plugins with Vite, more specifically jQuery plugins.
I'm trying to integrate the jquery.scrollTo plugin into my Laravel project but unfortunately I get an error message telling me that jQuery is not defined. I believe the problem is that the plugin is called before jQuery is ready. Anyone have an idea of how to overcome this problem?
resources/js/app.js
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = jQuery;


import './bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import 'jquery.scrollto';

vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],

    resolve: {

        alias: {

            '$': 'jQuery'

        },

    },
});

welcome.blade.php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="FR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    
  </body>
</html>


helps?
